# Java System.out.println() performance througth Telnet

Tags: java, performance, telnet

Can it change the performance of an application on an embedded system (J9 JVM) if the output is shown through telnet? It seems that in this way the system runs better during development that when the system is in production and don't run through telnet. `System.out.println()` sentences are not deleted in source code (this code smells i know).

Any suggestion? I suppose that all `System.out.println()` sentences are are undermining the performance of the virtual machine...

Comment: It depends on what `System.out` points to...

Comment: Can you explain this please?

Comment: `System.out`, ie stdout, can either be a very speedy terminal to which writing a bazillion of text takes virtually no time, or a very slow serial port. If the latter, `System.out` will be a bottleneck to your application.

Comment: I understand. Assuming that System.out is a bottleneck. Why is more pronounced if there is no connection via telnet to display the standard output if the connection is made to display the output?

Comment: Well, not knowing your setup, it is impossible to tell... Note that you can still redirect stdout if you want. However the best solution here would probably be to use a logging framework and use its logging methods instead of `println()`; if you want the output to appear on stdout as well you can always configure an appender for doing so

Answer (score 0):

The cost of println is significant but if you have a down stream bottleneck e.g. bandwidth, the cost doesn't matter and it is this bottleneck which matters.

In this situation you have to elevate the bottleneck.

Comment: I think I have not explained well. The problem is that the application works best when drawn through telnet that when run stand-alone mode

Comment: @unnder In that case you might be using special characters which are emulated differently in your telnet program as your DOS window.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have not explained well. The problem is that the application works best when drawn through telnet that when run stand-alone mode